# Getting a texture output from GLSL shader to opengl

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I have a GLSL shader that compares two masks, and colours the pixel with the image of the highest value. I want to output that to a texture that stores at each pixel the highest mask for example 
I have img1,img2,img3 and mask1,mask2,mask3

now the shader does the following

```
if mask1 >= mask2
gl_FragColor = img1
else
gl_FragColor = img2
```

So, if for the first pixel mask1 is highest, I would like to store in my output texture 0 and do that for each pixel

then after finishing the shader execution I would like to have a texture in my opengl code that stores for each pixel either 0 or 1 which shows what mask has the larger value.

Is there a possible way to do that ?

Comment: What is the part of this that you're having problems with? Rendering to a texture or doing the logic in the fragment shader?

Comment: so at each pixel Ill be colouring the screen with either img1 or img2 in addition to that I want another texture to store 0 or 1, 0 if it is mask1 and 1 if it is the other and then use that texture later in my opengl code